# Controlar volume de vídeo em Banner Interstitial AdMob

Tags: android, admob

Estou utilizando em meu app banners interstitiais admob. Está havendo reclamações dos usuários de que o volume dos vídeos exibidos nesse tipo de banner (geralmente os vídeos são sobre jogos) estão altos. Logicamente eu sei que o volume dos vídeos é o mesmo em que o volume do dispositivo do usuário está configurado.

A minha pergunta é a seguinte, tem como controlar ou pausar o volume desses vídeos nos interstitiais admob via programação através do próprio aplicativo?

Desde já eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade não exatamente, você não tem nenhum controle total sobre esses vídeos, nem em volume nem em tempo. A única coisa que é "controlável" é a categoria de vídeos apresentados nesse tipo de anúncio (Só pra evitar anúncios indevidos para crianças e etc) e o volume do Celular com a API do Admob.

Admob Docs: [Documentação do Admob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/global-settings)

Comment: Já fiz o bloqueio de alguns jogos no Admob, mas você bloqueia um e aparecem outros. Geralmente esses anúncios são aqueles que apresentam vídeos demonstrativos desses jogos e possibilita que o usuário instale o jogo se ele quiser. Mas de qualquer forma vou dar uma olhada na documentação e ver se acho algo que se possa fazer. Obrigado.

Comment: **Sem problemas, a documentação é bem ampla, algo ai deve te ajudar.**

Comment: li a documentação e fiz testes no aplicativo utilizando `MobileAds.initialize(this)` e `MobileAds.setAppVolume(0.2f)` mas não obtive a redução do volume do som do anúncio.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode baixar o volume do dispositivo utilizando uma propaganda, por motivos de segurança. Imagine se qualquer propaganda pudesse controlar esse tipo de coisa - logo teríamos propagandas ativando a localização á força para saber onde o usuário está com mais precisão, propagandas ativando a câmera para ver o que o usuário vê etc.

A melhor saída é reduzir o volume nos vídeos. Experimente testar o vídeo em alguns aparelhos e veja se com o volume máximo fica desconfortável.